# Does this example represent "Prototypal Inheritance"?

Tags: javascript, html, inheritance, prototype

I have got an object literal (a), which I later use to make another object (b) add some properties, and again make an object with help of (b), ie (c) and add some properties to it.

Finally, I try access c.name which browser goes on for searching first in c, then b, then finally gets it from object a (same for second alert). But, I am a bit confused if this example correctly represents "Prototypal Inheritance"! (As, function constructure with prototype properties is not involved).

```js
var a = {name: "Jenny", age: 27}; 
var b = Object.create(a); 
b.state = "New York"; 
var c = Object.create(b); 
c.flag = "50 star flag"; 
alert(c.name); 
alert(b.age);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does, the prototype chain you created is `c -> b -> a`.

```js
var a = {};
var b = Object.create(a);

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(b) === a); // true

var c = Object.create(b);

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(c) === b); // true
```

If you're confused about missing constructor functions in this example, remember that `Object.create` is just a shortcut for

```
function Object.create(proto) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = proto;
    return new F();
}
```

so the `new` and constructor are still executed under the hood. For the rationale behind `Object.create` see this [classic article](https://crockford.com/javascript/prototypal.html).